# Efficient way to initialize array with a byte sequence?

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I have a byte sequence of some size `n` (which could be 1..4 elements in the "real" code), with `n = 3` for the sake of this example:

```
char source[n] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' }
```

And I have a memory range of sufficient size to hold `m` copies of this sequence:

```
char * dest = new char[m*n]
```

(And yes, I know `std::vector`, and yes, it's generally to be preferred over `new`'ing your own memory, and no, it's not an option for the code I am currently working on -- and anyway the problem would still be the same.)

Now I want to initialize `dest` with those `m` copies of `source`. There are various ways to do `m` copies of a single value, but apparently none for doing `m` copies of a *sequence* of values. Sure, I could use a nested loop:

```
for ( unsigned i1 = 0; i1 < m; ++i1 )
{
    for ( unsigned i2 = 0; i2 < n; ++i2 )
    {
        dest[ i1 * n + i2 ] = source[ i1 ];
    }
}
```

But somehow this lacks all the finesse that usually tells me that I got the "right" solution for a problem.

Does C++ offer some more efficient way for this?

Comment: Any reason you don't use `std::vector`?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Yes, several. Not part of the question. `std::vector` is not an option in the larger scheme this problem is a part of.

Comment: @DevSolar Try using `memcpy` to avoid nested loop.

Comment: `n` would be 4 for `char source[n] = "abc"`.

Comment: Write c++ that clearly expresses intent.  Use standard containers and algorithms when possible (almost always). The optimiser will produce efficient code.

Comment: This rather depends on whether you want generic, portable C++, or can use some knowledge of the platform on which it runs. If it's the latter, you could use a VPU to parallelize the outer loop to some extent.

I suspect using `memcpy()` is probably a good portable choice if `n` is larger than a cache-line, for the simple reason that its implementation will probably make use of the VPU and pre-caching instructions.

Things that are likely to be bad for performance are reversing the order of the two loops.

Comment: Incidentally, it's a fair game for a compiler to convert calls to std library functions into inline, compiler generated, code. `memcpy()` is a good candidate for this.  For instance, if the compiler deduced that you were copying exactly four bytes, it could simply replace the call to `memcpy` with a 32-bit load and store.

Comment: @marko: If I could rely on it to be four bytes, it would be easy. But it could be anything from 1..4 bytes, which is what makes this thing tricky...

Comment: @DevSolar Is it possible to waste a little space after the source array (essentially padding it out to a minimum of 4 bytes), always copy the maximum four bytes, but only increment the index of `dest` by the actual size being copied?

Comment: @MichaelAlbers: Length of the initializing sequence could be 1..4 in my specific case. (Updated the question accordingly.) Padding wouldn't be a problem for me.

Comment: By *efficient*, you mostly take to mean the syntax or performance?

Comment: For something this simple, it is not going to matter how you code it. The speed will be limited by memory.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: I have seen the deleted comment, you deserve an explanation. The project is a Unicode-aware string class wrapping the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/) -- since the string class they provide, `UnicodeString`, is very Java-flavored and positively clunky in C++ context. Using the C++ API is therefore not an option, and the C API functions work on arrays. Using `std::vector` as storage backend would involve lots of marshalling / un-marshalling copies. That is why I am working with arrays *in this special case*; your comment is of course correct for the general case.

Comment: @Lingxi: Both, in an ideal world, but since I don't think this particular constructor will be used that often, I selected your solution mostly for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this give you a right feeling? (see it live [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lcA2A8CJR2f7a1As))

```
auto it = dest;
while ((it = std::copy(source, source + n, it)) 
       != dest + m * n);
```

Answer (score 1):

zero-initialising is the most efficient.  Where m is large and access sparse particularly, the OS may even use soft page faults to do COW of the same virtual zero-ed memory page for example, lazy allocating the requested memory when it's actually used.

Now, if you XOR every store & load from the byte arrary, with the appropriate byte from source, you can change the meaning of the NULL bit pattern.

```
dest[ i] = c1 ^ source[ i % n];  // store update
c2 = dest[ j] ^ source[ j % n];  // load, if dest[ j] is 0 it was never updated
```

In modern Out Of Order CPUs operations are not expensive compared to memory cache misses.

What you do need for this technique is to allocate the byte arrary in an OS specific way that guarantees it is zero-ed eg) mmap under Linux

Answer (score 1):

I would use `std::copy` or `std::copy_n` in a for loop:

```
for( int i = 0; i < m; ++i )
   std::copy_n(source, n, dest+n*i );

for( int i = 0; i < m; ++i )
   std::copy(source, source+n, dest+n*i );
```

Answer (score 0):

If `m` is large, and your `memcpy` is faster than a byte-based loop, it may be worth while doing an 'expanding binary fill' (I don't know what it's called because I just made it up). The idea is this:

- Prime the destination array by copying `n` bytes from `source` to `dest`
- Copy `n` bytes from `dest` to `dest+n`
- Copy `2*n` bytes from `dest` to `dest+2*n`
- Copy `4*n` bytes from `dest` to `dest+4*n`
- Copy `8*n` bytes from `dest` to `dest+8*n`
- ...

until you have filled at least half the destination array. Now you can fill `dest` with one more copy.

This might actually be slower than a naive version, depending on things like caching. So if you do try this, you will have to run some performance tests.